# Sync Gantt charts with iCal

Tags: sync, calendar.app, gantt

Is it there any Gantt project management software that syncs or shows tasks directly in iCal, or with Google Calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=5348110+2802105087632869764&pli=1) works with google calendar.

Comment: Are you sure? It's a third-party gadget for Google Docs Spreadsheet, but I don't think it links with Google Calendar. Could you elaborate on how this is done?

Comment: [here](http://howtotechtips.blogspot.com/2008/06/import-list-of-events-into-google.html) for instructions, its not so easy, but its do-able. And you can reverse it to go from calander to the app.

Comment: it looks kind of complicated ...

Comment: I agree its not simple, but it should work.

Comment: That link is just a generic description of manually importing CSV into Google Calendar. It doesn't have anything to do with the Gantt chart gadget, and doesn't describe the reverse process (exporting from Google Calendar into Google Docs).